# Fast input string in single line without array in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have to input string once in single line and then iterate char by char in the fastest posible way.
I tried gets, fgets, fread, scanf but these functions requaire to use array like there:

```
char* array = new char[100000];
fgets(array,100000,stdin);
//gets(array);
//scanf("%[^\n]s", array);
```

Mayby there is faster way to read line for e.g without array ?
I need to use each char only once.
I tried to use fgetc but it doesn't work.

```
char c;
while((c=fgetc(stdin))!='\n'){
    if(c==' ') c=fgetc(stdin); // if char is a space go to next char from input
       //code
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work"? this means what?

Comment: There is no language C/C++ and nothing here indicates you are using C++. A "natural" C++ answer won't compile with a C compiler.

Comment: Getting 1 character at a time will most likely be slower than reading a line at a time. What is the purpose of this need to optimize reading from stdin?

Comment: No, there is no faster method to read more than one character without using an array of some sort (e.g. string, vector, etc.).  The character input functions read in more than one character.  Why the restriction of not using an array?

Answer (score -1):

Use String.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    str[1];
    str[2];
    str[3];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't read a "line", and `std::string` starts with a lower case `s`. You also don't need to get the `c_str` to access the characters.

Comment: This is the most illiterate answer in every sense.  Every single line has something wrong with it, often profoundly so. Please rubber duck this.

Comment: Forget that all. Wrote from memory.